# ffmpeg taking so much time to extract frames from mpeg-ts file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I got a problem from one mpeg-ts video. Actually it was created by some one else and even I don't know how they are created. The problem is that, ffmpeg is taking so much time to decode all frames from the mpeg-ts video. The command I used for this operation is...

**ffmpeg -i shame-run.mov -r 24/1 test/output%d.jpg**

Actually my application is integrated with ffmpeg v2.1.1. and I had a code for detecting black frames in a mpeg-ts video. Here, my code is not able to detect all black frames from ffmpeg for this mpeg-ts video. So, I taken standalone ffmpeg of same version as mentioned above and decoded standalone. But, it is taking so much time i.e., it is taken half an hour for decoding 1 min duration video.

So, is there any reason is that ffmpeg not able to extract as fast as required, and is there any reason that video got some errors.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Show the console output for this command. Also, why `-r`? This will duplicate/drop frames if video FPS is different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: But, when ffmpeg extracting the frames, I observed that fps = -1.6 to 1.2 (at some interval of time) but the actual fps=29.97. Can I know the reason of this observation.

Comment: That is the processing speed, not the input or output file's fps. Show console output.